# ASP.NET Core Web API & Autofac: resolve from container, but inside a controller's GET method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, autofac

Here's my project: ASP.NET Core Web API with Autofac.

I got the Autofac working fine: it injects all the services/classes I registered automatically. It's so beautiful!

I need to take it a step further, and looking to resolve `class`s using their `Name`, in a `GET` method on one of the API controller.

This is my registration:

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(automationAssembly)
    .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractParentClass)))
    .Named<AbstractParentClass>(t => t.Name);
```

And this is where I am stuck, trying to `resolve` the named class

```cs
[HttpGet("{className}")]
public string Get(string className) 
{
    Container.ResolveNamed("className", "AbstractParentClass") // => not sure how to get `Container` here
    return "value " + className;
}
```

I somehow need to get access to Autofac's `Container`, but not sure how to get it in the ASP.NET Core Web API setup.

[It's called `app` in `Program.cs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#register-the-database-context)

Any ideas anyone? TIA

Comment: Have you looked at using the built-in `HttpContext.RequestServices` property?  It would look something like:
 `var container = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IComponentContext>();

var instance = container.ResolveNamed(className, typeof(AbstractParentClass));
return "value" + className;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do what you need to do.

The first, and recommended, way, is to not [use the Autofac relationship types](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) to get what you need and not get the *current lifetime scope* at all.

```cs
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
  private IIndex<string, Lazy<AbstractParentClass>> _classes;
  public MyController(IIndex<string, Lazy<AbstractParentClass>> classes)
  {
    this._classes = classes;
  }

  [HttpGet("{name}")]
  public string Get(string name)
  {
    // Two steps here - get the Lazy<T> out of the IIndex<X, B>
    // then resolve the value from the Lazy<T>.
    var resolved = this._classes[name].Value;
    return resolved.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

You can combine relationships, and that's what you see here. You don't *actually* want to resolve every single instance of the registered types, you want to defer that - so `Lazy<T>` to defer it. Then you want to inspect the set of them and pick one by name - so `IIndex<X, B>`.

By doing that, you don't have to do service location at all.

However, if you don't like that and you're into service location, `ControllerBase` offers a bunch of helpful extensions to access the current request context.

```cs
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpGet("{name}")]
  public string Get(string name)
  {
    var scope = this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILifetimeScope>();
    var resolved = scope.ResolveNamed<AbstractBaseClass>(name);
    return resolved.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

Of course, you can make that even simpler by just injecting the current request lifetime scope.

```cs
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
  private ILifetimeScope _scope;
  public MyController(ILifetimeScope scope)
  {
    this._scope = scope;
  }

  [HttpGet("{name}")]
  public string Get(string name)
  {
    var resolved = this._scope.ResolveNamed<AbstractBaseClass>(name);
    return resolved.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

But, again, if it was me I'd probably use the first option with `IIndex<X, Lazy<B>>` so I wouldn't have to do service location anywhere.

Comment: `Lazy` deferral is even much better. I will readup more on this. Thank you very much :)